# add query on href using input

Tags: php, input, href

I have an

```
<input type=text name=search />
```

and I wanted to add the value of input to my href

```
<a href='index.php?search=$search>submit</a>
```

But I think that won't work on php alone right?

How can I add the value of my input to my href as it clicks?

NOTE: need to appear in the browser url menu this way

```
index.php?search=anyvalue
```

as soon as they click it. because I'm using pagination

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript to do that, also why not use a form

Comment: @Musa I tried used form and I'm having a limit to show the result. the problem with that is, I put some pagination. For example I click page 2, the result won't show anymore because it can't read anymore what is type before by the user. that code is for my SEARCH on my site. Get what I mean? Is there any remedy if I used the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight HTML - no PHP or JavaScript Needed

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="search" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Once clicked it will take the user to: `index.php?search={value of input}`

For pagination to work it would be:

```
<a href="index.php?search=<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>&page=2">Page 2</a>
<a href="index.php?search=<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>&page=3">Page 3</a>
```

Comment: @IvorySantos Check the bit about pagination.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<form method="get" action="index.php">
<input name="search"  type="text" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

If that's not what your looking for just elaborate a bit on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

you must open a php tag like this:

```
<a href='index.php?search=<?php echo $search;?>' >submit</a>
```

but it work after submitting the form.
use javascript